# Gradle with Selenium Testing failing in Github Actions but passing locally

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gradle, github-actions, cicd

I am currently working on trying to connect Selenium automation scripts to be run using Github action. I decided on using Gradle from how easy it looked to use when running these Selenium tests locally and in Github actions. I have been able to get these Selenium tests to work just fine locally using `./gradlew test`. I have also been writing all of this using Visual Studio Code.

Here is my gradle.yml:

```
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: ["dev"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["dev"]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 19
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: "19"
          distribution: "temurin"
      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew
      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew clean test
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This is a general purpose Gradle build.
 * Learn more about Gradle by exploring our samples at https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/samples
 * This project uses @Incubating APIs which are subject to change.
 */
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.1'
    testImplementation("io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.3.2")
}
```

settings.gradle file:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * The settings file is used to specify which projects to include in your build.
 *
 * Detailed information about configuring a multi-project build in Gradle can be found
 * in the user manual at https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
 * This project uses @Incubating APIs which are subject to change.
 */
plugins {
    id("com.gradle.enterprise") version("3.9")
}

gradleEnterprise {
    if (System.getenv("CI") != null) {
        buildScan {
            publishAlways()
            termsOfServiceUrl = "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service"
            termsOfServiceAgree = "yes"
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = 'it-mendix-ci-kaizen-events'
```

And my Selenium java file:

```
import org.junit.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.io.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.WindowType;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;


import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;

public class CIHomePage {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupWebdriverChromeDriver() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors","--disable-extensions","--no-sandbox","--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void homePageTitle() throws InterruptedException{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 45);
        driver.get("https://notarealurl.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Ecom_Password")).sendKeys("notarealpassword");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Ecom_User_ID")).sendKeys("notarealusername");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton2")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Continuous Improvement - Event Name Overview"));

    }

}
```

When these test run in Github actions I receive this error.

```
Exception
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for title to be "Continuous Improvement - Event Name Overview". Current title: "Access Manager" (tried for 45 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)    
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'    
System info: host: 'fv-az1028-100', ip: '10.1.0.192', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-1033-azure', java.version: '19.0.2'   
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver    
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 110.0.5481.177, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8e..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.Mh8RwC}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:42651}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:42651/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 110.0.5481.177, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}  
Session ID: ca87e954431ab0747fceab555c07e562
```

From what I can tell, the error keeps happening when Selenium is trying to log into SSO and can't get past this page to be directed to the site that I am working on. I have been able to get this to work just fine locally on my machine. This also is not an issue when Selenium isn't directed to log into our SSO. I have been able to get the scripts to work just fine when directing to a site without our SSO.

I am not sure if it is an issue with how I set up my gradle.yml file or need to do something different with how I wrote the Selenium test file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the line of code is a little off. A quick demonstration:

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(("Google")));
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Google
  ```

---

### This usecase

Accordingly, your line of code should be:

```
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(("Continuous Improvement - Event Name Overview")));
```

Comment: I updated my code to look like this: driver.get("https://devcontinuousimprovement.vermeer.com/index.html");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Ecom_Password")).sendKeys("blank");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Ecom_User_ID")).sendKeys("blank");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton2")).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(("Continuous Improvement - Event Name Overview"))); 
But still getting the same error in the Github actions. The test ran just fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, it was because logging into our SSO it requires a two-factor authentication so the server was unable to login after receiving the information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).